# Does leveldb/Cassandra's bloom filter help in range query?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, bigtable, leveldb

I understand that leveldb/cassandra stores their records in SSTable, and use bloom filter to select SSTable on performing exact key query, does their bloom filter help in key range query?

Answer (score 4):

There are two types of range queries in Cassandra: get_slice, which finds a range of columns within a row, and get_range_slices, which finds a range of columns from a range of rows.

Bloom filters are used in get_slice to locate the row.  But Bloom filters aren't used in a get_range_slices query.  However, since Cassandra keys are stored in hash order, get_range_slices isn't very useful so having to scan all SSTables to perform a get_range_slices query doesn't normally matter.

Answer (score 1):

Before going into range query, it is important to know what is bloom filter?

> Bloom filters are probabilistic sets that allow you to trade memory
>   for accuracy or  is a space-efficient probabilistic data structure
>   that is used to test whether an element is a member of a set.

Cassandra uses bloom filters to save IO when performing a key lookup and as you know each SSTable has a bloom filter associated with it that Cassandra checks before doing any disk seeks. Now consider the situation without bloom filters, every read of a key would have to read every sstable, which is prohibitively expensive. By using bloom filters, cassandra almost always only has to look in the sstables which contain data for that key.

So whenever a range query is getting executed, bloom filters plays a significant rule. In get_slice sort of range query, it will help to identify the exact row and in get_range_slices it will help in finding the set of probabilistic keys responsible.

Comment: Bloom filters can't be used for get_range_slices - a Bloom filter cannot answer the question 'does the filter contain a key in the range X to Y'. It can only answer 'does the filter contain X'.

Comment: Richard exactly, so if we can get the information 'does the filter contain X', will indirectly help. Whats say?

Comment: Not without querying the Bloom filter for *every* key in the range X to Y. Depending on the type, this could even be unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

Richard answered bloom filter side; to to fill in the first part: yes, LeveledCompactionStrategy will generally result in faster scans (either by PK or index), due to more aggressive write-side merging of the data rows.